# Mongodb 2dsphere disallow empty geometry

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Is there any *strict mode* for 2dsphere geometry index in mongodb?

Can mongodb prevent storage of *empty* geometries (empty list, empty dict)?

Test-case:

```js
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.0.6
...
> use geotest
switched to db geotest
> db.places.createIndex({'geometry': '2dsphere'})
{
        "createdCollectionAutomatically" : true,
        "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
        "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
        "ok" : 1
}
```

...so far so good.

```js
> db.places.insert({'geometry': [[]]})  // this fails -> good
WriteResult({
        "nInserted" : 0,
        "writeError" : {
                "code" : 16755,
                "errmsg" : "Can't extract geo keys: { _id: ObjectId('5c8a483bcebc3f30972cb9ea'), geometry: [ [] ] }  Point must only contain numeric elements"
        }
})
```

...very happy this fails, but this:

```js
> db.places.insert({'geometry': []})    // can I make mongo fail here too?
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.places.insert({'geometry': {}})    // and here?
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.places.insert({'geometry': null})  // how about this one?
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.places.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c8a4840cebc3f30972cb9eb"), "geometry" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c8a4843cebc3f30972cb9ec"), "geometry" : {  } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c8a4b23cebc3f30972cb9ee"), "geometry" : null }
```

...doesn't fail. Can i make this fail somehow?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @alex-blex for the tip!

Using validator for new collections:

```js
> db.createCollection("places", {validator: {"geometry.type": {$in:
... ["Point", "MultiPoint", "LineString", "MultiLineString", "Polygon", "MultiPolygon"]
... }}})
{ "ok" : 1 }
> db.places.createIndex({'geometry': '2dsphere'})
{
        "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
        "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
        "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Now we're unable to insert empty geometries:

```js
> db.places.insert({'geometry': []})
WriteResult({
        "nInserted" : 0,
        "writeError" : {
                "code" : 121,
                "errmsg" : "Document failed validation"
        }
})
> db.places.insert({'geometry': {}})
WriteResult({
        "nInserted" : 0,
        "writeError" : {
                "code" : 121,
                "errmsg" : "Document failed validation"
        }
})
> db.places.insert({'geometry': null})
WriteResult({
        "nInserted" : 0,
        "writeError" : {
                "code" : 121,
                "errmsg" : "Document failed validation"
        }
})
```

To add validator to an existing collection:

```js
> db.places.createIndex({'geometry': '2dsphere'})
{
        "createdCollectionAutomatically" : true,
        "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
        "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
        "ok" : 1
}
> db.runCommand({ collMod: 'places', validator: {"geometry.type": {$in:
... ["Point", "MultiPoint", "LineString", "MultiLineString", "Polygon", "MultiPolygon"]
... }}})
{ "ok" : 1 }
```